# TFS Check-in Unavailable

Tags: c#, tfs

I have a C# project that is booked into TFS.  However, for some reason one of the forms within the project has not booked in.  I can’t work out how to force this to book in, as right-clicking on the source file doesn’t give me the option to check-in.

All the other files in the project are booked in, and I can see them using the Source Control Explorer, however, this file isn’t in there.  Can anyone tell me how this could have happened, and how to force this file to check-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click in the source control explorer directory where the files live and select the Add Items to Folder Option.

This typically happens if you create the files outside of visual studio. That being said, TFS is flaky at best.

Comment: Nothing flaky about the behavior at all.  It is quite possible that TFS was running in Offline Mode, due to losing connectivity with the server.  The answer is appropriate, but the snarky comment is just your opinion.  Last thing you want is for it to add everything automatically.  Not everything under a Workspace mapping belongs in TFS.  Things like .trx files from local test runs, application logs, binaries, installers, etc.  There are many things that are either supporting an application or generated by an application that just don't fit in the world of being under version control.

Comment: I meant that VS was running in offline mode from losing connectivity to TFS.  ;-)  Not enough coffee yet, this morning.

Comment: It *is* flaky if you create the files correctly in visual studio. I've had this occur when connected the server with no warnings or errors given. Also, random crashes opening properties pages when we moved to TFS2008. If you had a new project that hadn't been checked in when this happened, it got toasted, and you would have to manually fix project files in notepad or revert and start again. If the TFS server has a close to full disk, you get failures attempting to get the latest version. Sometimes, work items queries when checking in don't work until you reset all your visual studio user data.